# How can I certify an ultralight design as complying with part 103?

Tags: faa-regulations, ultralight, aircraft-certification

Can you help me about which procedure do I need to follow in order to have a certificate that my design is part 103 ultralight.

And as a information how long would it take to get the certificate and about how much?

What would be the first step?

Thank you.

Comment: Unless you plan on quantity production, you may be overcomplicating this -- there are lots of legal Part 103 craft flying that are one-off, so the process can't be too hard.

Comment: @ZeissIkon Commercial production of an uncertified product does not need any type of certificate either and there is no process.

Answer (score 3):

No certificate needed and "satisfactory evidence" is only needed "upon request". From the [FARs](https://www.eaa.org/eaa/aviation-interests/ultralights/getting-started-in-ultralight-flying/about-faa-part-103-for-ultralights):

> 103.1   Applicability.
>
> This part prescribes rules governing the operation of ultralight vehicles in the United States. For the purposes of this part, an ultralight vehicle is a vehicle that:
>
> (a) Is used or intended to be used for manned operation in the air by a single occupant; >(b) Is used or intended to be used for recreation or sport purposes only; (c) Does not have any U.S. or foreign airworthiness certificate; and (d) If unpowered, weighs less than 155 pounds;
>
> or (e) If powered: (1) Weighs less than 254 pounds empty weight, excluding floats and safety devices which are intended for deployment in a potentially catastrophic situation; (2) Has a fuel capacity not exceeding 5 U.S. gallons; (3) Is not capable of more than 55 knots calibrated airspeed at full power in level flight; and (4) Has a power-off stall speed which does not exceed 24 knots calibrated airspeed.
>
> § 103.3   Inspection requirements.
>
> (a) Any person operating an ultralight vehicle under this part shall, upon request, allow the Administrator, or his designee, to inspect the vehicle to determine the applicability of this part. 
>   (b) The pilot or operator of an ultralight vehicle must, **upon request** of the Administrator, furnish **satisfactory evidence** that the vehicle is subject only to the provisions of this part.
>
> 103.7   Certification and registration.
>
> (a) Notwithstanding any other section pertaining to certification of aircraft or their parts or equipment, ultralight vehicles and their component parts and equipment are **not required** to meet the airworthiness certification standards specified for aircraft or **to have certificates of airworthiness**.

Comment: Need to start from a point but from where dont know yet, want to apply for my ultralight in order to be able to sell as a comertial part 103 ultralight.

Comment: @AliMa You can't apply for something that does not exist.